# XSLT: Change attribute value everywhere

Tags: xml, xslt

I have XML files of unknown/different structure. I have to change the value of an attribute.
 **This is just an example** and the structure can be anything:

```
<root>
    <SomeElement endTime='12:00:00' />
    <subLevel>
        <OtherElement endTime='14:00:00' />
    </subLevel>
</root>
```

I need to change the `endTime` attribute everywhere it occurs. The output should be

```
<root>
    <SomeElement endTime='11:59:59' />
    <subLevel>
        <OtherElement endTime='13:59:59' />
    </subLevel>
</root>
```

I could do this if I knew the exact position of the attribute but how to do it if I just don't know the structure of the XML file and need to change it for every element in the file? Is that even possible?

Comment: is the element always in the same descendant?

Comment: No. It can be anywhere

Comment: now i see your issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add to the identity transformation,

**XSLT v3.0 only**

```
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
```

**XSLT v1.0-x.x**

```
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
```

an override for `@endTime` which will replace the existing values with one a second earlier:

```
  <xsl:param name="datePart">2017-12-04T</xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="@endTime">
    <xsl:attribute name="endTime">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(xs:dateTime(concat($datePart,.))
                            - xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S'),$datePart)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>
```

by temporarily prepending a date so that the built-in dateTime calculation functions can be used.

### Full XSLT

(Datetime calculations require XSLT 2.0 or higher)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
                xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
                xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:param name="datePart">2017-12-04T</xsl:param>
  <xsl:template match="@endTime">
    <xsl:attribute name="endTime">
      <xsl:value-of select="substring-after(xs:dateTime(concat($datePart,.))
                            - xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S'),$datePart)"/>
    </xsl:attribute>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**applied to your XML input:**

```
<root>
    <SomeElement endTime='12:00:00' />
    <subLevel>
        <OtherElement endTime='14:00:00' />
    </subLevel>
</root>
```

**provides your requested XML output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<root>
    <SomeElement endTime="11:59:59"/>
    <subLevel>
        <OtherElement endTime="13:59:59"/>
    </subLevel>
</root>
```

**as requested.**

Answer (score 2):

Well, if you know how to alter that value then write a template

```
<xsl:template match="@endTime">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}">
   <!-- code to alter value here -->
  </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>
```

and handle the rest with the identity transformation, i.e. in XSLT 3 with `<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>` or in earlier versions with

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

In XSLT 2 or 3 you can directly use the substraction between an `xs:time` value and a duration to implement the change:

```
<xsl:template match="@endTime">
  <xsl:attribute name="{name()}" select="xs:time(.) - xs:dayTimeDuration('PT1S')"/>
</xsl:template>
```

No need to create an `xs:dateTime` first.

Online example at http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/b4GWV4